# virtualbox ppa for 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, ppa

I want to add a ppa to get virtualbox updates but I can't understand [the *debian-based* steps](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) on their webpage [(or here)](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-virtualbox-through-ppa-in-ubuntu-14101410-or-other-distributions). Normally I add repositories with `sudo add-apt-repository ...`

Can anyone explain the steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to add the repository to your system.  Copy and paste the following to a terminal window:

**VirtualBox no longer supports i386, so add the repository like this:**

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

Then you just step through the rest from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads; or I put the steps below.

You can just copy and paste each of these steps to finish your install of `VirtualBox` on your system:

Add the key:

Ubuntu 14.04 (No longer supported):

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Ubuntu 16.04 (no longer supported) and newer (18.04 and newer are supported still):

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then do your update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Virtualbox (6.1 is the newest for now):

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1
```

*If this is a new installation, run the following to add vboxusers group to your username:*

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER
```

*Then log out and back in for changes to take effect.*

Then after it is all installed, it is recommended to install the [VirtualBox Extension Pack from here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Hope this helps!

Comment: It would be helpful if we can generalize the question and your answer to also include 16.04 and 16.10. To do that, the only addition to your answer is to add `oracle_vbox_2016.asc` (as opposed to `oracle_vbox.asc`).

Comment: @edwinksl Thank you!  I added it as an addition for now as I don't know if it will work with 14.04 yet.  But thank you for great advice.  =)

Comment: Certainly works for 16.10; I just tried it.

Comment: @edwinksl I was worried about the 2016 key working with 14.04 that is still supported.

Comment: Oh. I think what you wrote is correct: `oracle_vbox.asc` for 14.04, `oracle_vbox_2016.asc` for 16.04 and newer.

Comment: Small recommendation: put the `deb` line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`, since that's a little bit cleaner and goes along with what that directory is for.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Good idea.  Changed.

Comment: @Terrance according to [ChaiT.Rex' suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759330/virtualbox-ppa-for-14-04#comment1617003_759340) you changed the commands, but not the explanation prior them, which can be a little bit confusing for beginners...

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Ah, I missed that part in the beginning.  Helps if I reread what I wrote in the first place.  =)

Comment: `sudo bash -c 'echo "..." > file'` is ugly. `echo "..." | sudo tee file` is much better.

Comment: Sure, sure, feel Free to tell people to do stupid things, that's a habit of yours it seems...

Comment: @fkraiem I have updated the line as that is what I have been doing now.  I am sorry for stating what I said in the past about the line.  You are correct that it much cleaner.  I think I was just really having a bad day that day.  Please forgive me!