# Kernel driver not installed

Tags: 16.04, kernel

Okay so I am trying to run windows 8.1 in virtual box but whenever I try to start it I get a error saying "Kernel driver not installed" and I have tried everything to fix it. And this command: $ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup doesn't work cause it says command not found. So any help also I am running on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: See my inquiry on your repost of this question.

Answer (score 1):

To install the kernel driver for Virtualbox, run the following command:

```
sudo apt install dkms
```

Also try this command as they moved the vboxdrv file:

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea I did that but somehow it still doesn't work

Comment: @SwerveOnDem  It's the right answer to the question you asked and the information you provided. It's not Terrance's fault if you asked the wrong question. Consider accepting this answer (since it's correct), and open a new question asking why dkms doesn't work for you.

Comment: @SwerveOnDem Updated for location of vboxdrv.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @SwerveOnDem I updated my answer to reflect for the /etc/init.d/vboxdrv file that was not found in your question.

Comment: Still get command not found :(

Comment: @SwerveOnDem Well, that is the only two locations that I am aware of.  How did you install VirtualBox?  Did you follow instructions like these:  http://askubuntu.com/a/759340/231142  ?

Comment: Yup did everything still won't work :( ty tho