# Virtualbox Extensionpack İssue

Tags: virtualbox

I installed virtualbox but i couldnt install extension pack.

VBoxExtPackRegister returned VERR_VERSION_MISMATCH, pReg=0000000000000000 ErrInfo='VirtualBox version mismatch - expected 5.2 got 5.0'.

Sonuç Kodu: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Bileşen: 
ExtPackManagerWrap
Arayüz: 
IExtPackManager {edba9d10-45d8-b440-1712-46ac0c9bc4c5}

That is the error, so how can i fix it ?

Comment: I threw together a step-by-step here based on VirtualBox website for installing through PPAs.  https://askubuntu.com/a/759340/231142

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have been mixing up Virtualbox from the Ubuntu repositories with Virtualbox from the www.virtualbox.org web site.
Check your Virtualbox release by selecting Help and About in the menu.
You have to download the extension pack of the same release from www.virtualbox.org, it seems you try to install extension pack 5.0.x on Virtualbox 5.2.x.
The latest release from Virtualbox is 5.2.6.

Comment: I checked my virtualbox and it was 5.0.4. So I removed from my pc and download latest version virtulbox from www.virtualbox.org but i cant install. that is the error : 
Error: Dependency not achieved: libqt5core5a (> = 5.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

What I do on my system, I install all packages that are indicated as missing dependencies. Normally you have say 4 of those, use the terminal and do:

> sudo apt install package-name